# Change position of Grid using animation C#

Tags: c#, wpf

WPF

```
<Grid Name="GhostGrid">
    <Image Source="img.jpg"/>
</Grid>
```

I am trying to change the position of a grid using animation. This is working fine -

C#

```
TranslateTransform transformImage = new TranslateTransform();
GhostGrid.RenderTransform = transformImage;
DoubleAnimation animationImage = new DoubleAnimation(0, -50, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.6));
transformImage.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, animationImage);
```

But this not working -
C#

```
DoubleAnimation animationImage = new DoubleAnimation()
{
     From = 0,
     To = -450,
     Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.8))
};
Storyboard.SetTarget(animationImage, GhostGrid);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animationImage,new PropertyPath(TranslateTransform.XProperty));
storyBoard = new Storyboard();
storyBoard.Children.Add(animationImage);
storyBoard.Begin();
```

Comment: The first code snippet animates the X property of a TranslateTransform, while the second tries to animate the X property of a Grid. Obviously, the latter does not exist. Try `new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.X")`, provided you have also assigned a TranslateTransform to the Grid's RenderTransform.

Comment: Thanks, Its working now.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Clemens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1136211/clemens) suggestion its working now -

```
DoubleAnimation animationImage = new DoubleAnimation()
{
     From = 0,
     To = -450,
     Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.8))
};
Storyboard.SetTarget(animationImage, GhostGrid);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animationImage,new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.X"));
storyBoard = new Storyboard();
storyBoard.Children.Add(animationImage);
storyBoard.Begin();
```